# Can there be 2 names in surname in a U.S. passport?

Tags: visas, usa, passports

My name in my other documents is Harsha N R.:

- first name Harsha
- surname: Nidanur Rajappa

*Nidanur* is my native place, and *Rajappa* is my father's name.

Can there be two names in the surname column, like *Nidanur Rajappa*?

Comment: Yes, you can have two last names, or even no last name at all.. some tribes in Indonesia for example have only first names, while some other groups around the world (like you) have two last names.. Arabs for example can have up to 5 or even more names (first, second, thirs...etc)

Comment: I have five names!  I randomly put 1 or 2 in the "Nom" section to confuse authorities  :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Your first name will appear in the *First name* field and everything else will appear in the *Surname* field. The *Surname* field is not restricted to a single word.

Answer (score 1):

I have a compound first name (this can be problematic) because in some applications they put the second part of my first name in the middle name field; but multiple family/surnames are not a problem.

Speaking of Arabic names, the name is (for males, and is written without dashes):

First Name - Last Name - Father's First Name - Father's Last Name

In my case, my father also has a compound first name, so you can imagine the fun I have living in Kuwait.

However, in the application you should put your full *legal* name. The name that appears in your travel document (generally a passport), and it should have the exact same *latin spelling* as well.

Comment: Yep. I have a Spanish name and have a similar issue. FirstName + Middle + FathersLast + MothersLast... Airport control people don't like long names ><